# How to setup gevent monitor thread with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, gevent

I am using `gevent` workers with `gunicorn` for my `flask` application. I am facing issues where my greenlets are getting blocked for long periods. gevent provides [monitoring](http://www.gevent.org/monitoring.html)
via monitor threads. Is it possible to setup this monitor thread when using gevent workers with gunicorn. If yes , can someone share a possible example. I have looked up multiple example but none of them are working.
versions being used in my application

```
python==3.8
gevent==21.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable this we have to set the environment variable `GEVENT_MONITOR_THREAD_ENABLE` and that enables the monitor. For more configuration we can refer the doc [here](https://www.gevent.org/configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like hub does not get switched to so the monitor thread not started, you can enable monitor thread manually using

```py
hub = gevent.get_hub()
hub.start_periodic_monitoring_thread()
```

But there is a problem with event gevent monitoring which is spamming issue
https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1665